# Solving the next differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble resolving this equations. I know i have to substitute $y$ to $z$ so in the first one: $z' = y''$ ; $z = y'$ and it would be like: $z'+z'^2 = 1$. But i don't know what to do next

- $yy''+y'^2=1$
- $4y'' = xy'^{2}$

Comment: $z'^2+z'-1=0$ means $z'=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: @Nosrati I don't think is Cauchy-Euler. The Possible outcomes are: $y^2 = x^2+c2$ ; $y^2 = c1 + x^2$ ; $y^2 = x^2$ ; $y^2 - c1 = (x+c2)^2$

Comment: For the first $$yy'' + y'^{2} = (yy')' = \left( \frac{1}{2} y^{2} \right)''$$ For the second, let $y' = z$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the first equation $$y''+y'^2=1$$ As you wrote, let $z=y'$ and now consider
$$z'+z^2=1$$ Now, inverse ($x$ being the variable) as
$$\frac 1 {x'}+z^2=1\implies x'=\frac1{1-z^2}\implies x+C=\int \frac{dz}{1-z^2}=\frac 12\log \left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$$ Now, extract $z$ and ... continue.

Comment: I did a small modification, instead of $y''$ is $yy''$

Comment: @Neto_Lozano. Make $y=\sqrt z$ and look what happens.